# New lines in hidden cells are ommited, how to get the compete innerText?

Tags: javascript, html

The new lines in hidden table cells are lost. How can I get the text with the new lines from the innerText of hidden cells?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(`This is innerText of visible td: ${document.getElementById("td2").innerText}`);
  console.log(`This is same innerText of hidden td: ${document.getElementById("td3").innerText}`);
  console.log(`New lines are lost. How can I get the text with the new lines from innerText of hidden cells?`);
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

table.tbl {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.tbl td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr>
      <td>Table cell 1</td>
      <td id="td2">Table cell 2 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
      <td id="td3" class="hide">Table cell 3 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `innerHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML
```

I added another row where the contents of both cells from row 1 are copied ussing `innerHTML`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //console.log(`This is same innerHTML of hidden td: ${document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML}`);
    document.getElementById("td2-copy").innerHTML = document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("td3-copy").innerHTML = document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML;
    console.log(document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML);

})
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
table.tbl {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.tbl td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="tbl">
            <tr>
                <td>Table cell 1</td>
                <td id="td2">Table cell 2 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
                <td id="td3" class="hide">Table cell 3 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Table cell 1 copy</td>
                <td id="td2-copy">Table cell 2 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
                <td id="td3-copy">Table cell 3 with newLines<br>New line1<br>NewLine2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

According to the `innerText` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

> The innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants. As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.

There is also a clear [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText#example) showing exactly the issue you are facing. That is expected behavior for innerText

Comment: I use the hidden column to store some little comments, which can include another snippets of html code. So I think I can not use InnerHtml not to get them mixed. I'd like to stay with text.

Comment: I updated my answer. In short, you can not do it with innerText on the hidden elements